# what is the syntax for writing formulas into an existing excel sheet in using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I'm trying to convert what i've written in VBA into an executable file using c#.  I idea is to write certain formulas into an existing excel workbook.  I have the syntax for writing into a new workbook, but not into an existing work book.

Answer (score 3):

**Tried and Tested**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

            // Open a File
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\MyFile.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

            // Set Sheet 1 as the sheet you want to work with
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // REST OF THE CODE HERE TO INTERACT WITH THE WORKSHEET//
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            //Once done close and quit Excel
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlexcel.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlexcel);
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the `Workbooks.Open` method, this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5123/Opening-and-Navigating-Excel-with-C) provides the details.

```
string workbookPath = "c:/SomeWorkBook.xls";
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
        0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
        true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

You can then reference a specific sheet via the `Worksheets` property.

```
Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for info.  It will take me a while to work through it as I'm a newbie, but i'll report back as I go.  Thanks again.